# App not showing up in Google play store on some phones

Tags: android, android-studio, google-play

I just made an app and published it. It shows up on some phones but others you can't find it.  I have tried everything but cannot figure out what I did wrong. The app does show up on my phone and three others when searching directly for the name (lonelywizard) but I have to physically send a link or the other phone of the same version cannot even see it. Here is the [link](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.lod.kalas.lonelywizard) to the app as well.
 If I need any more information on here let me know

here is the xml.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.lod.kalas.lonelywizard"
    android:versionCode="3"
    android:versionName="@string/app_name">



    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE"/>
    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@drawable/icon"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
    <meta-data android:name="com.google.android.gms.games.APP_ID"
        android:value="@string/app_id" />
    <meta-data android:name="com.google.android.gms.version"
        android:value="@integer/google_play_services_version"/>
        <activity
            android:name=".MainActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>

        <activity android:name="com.google.android.gms.ads.AdActivity"
            android:configChanges="keyboard|keyboardHidden|orientation|screenLayout|uiMode|screenSize|smallestScreenSize"
            android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Translucent" />

    </application>

</manifest>
```

here is the build gradle

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 21
    buildToolsVersion "21.1.2"

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.lod.kalas.lonelywizard"
        minSdkVersion 11
        targetSdkVersion 21
        versionCode 4
        versionName "1.0.3"
    }

    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:21.0.3'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:6.+'
    compile project(':BaseGameUtils')
}
```

Comment: Please, attaсh your manifest code, may be it contain some permisions, that limit the number of devices

Comment: Do you use Android Studio? If so, please post the dependencies section from your `build.gradle` file. Some libraries define their own permission uses and all the manifests are merged together in the resulting `.apk`. (BTW: Play Store says I can't install this in my country - Czech Republic.)

Comment: I have fixed the problem with it not letting other countries download and added the manifest and gradle